# Assign each list a number that is not in that list

Tags: php

My title wording could be better. I'm going to start with a problem I have in general, explain the bigger picture and then come down to exact question.

I have a web application to host tournaments in and one of the cool features I thought on was to assign contestants tracks as well (so not only do calculations and provide UI, but also determine on which track the player should play on (imagine something like a bowling alley lane if you want to imagine a track)). The problem is that the player can not play on the same track if he has played on it either last game or the game before that (but can play if it's further down the line).

As contestants play against each other, my first (and only idea so far) was to iterate over each pair of players, check which tracks did they play on and add them into array called `playedTracks`.

Let's say this function is already finished and is returning correctly an array `playedTracks` with a maximum size of `4` (Four is when both players have played atleast three rounds and either hasn't played on the same track as other):

```
function getPlayedTracks($resultId,$opponentResultId,$currentRound){
    //Returns the list of tracks on which the pair has played on!
    $playedTracks = [];
    if ($currentRound == 1){
        //No tracks to pick from
        return [];
    }
    else if ($currentRound == 2){
        //One track to pick from
        $oneBehind = 1;
    }
    else{
        //Pick from two tracks
        $oneBehind = $currentRound - 1;
        $twoBehind = $currentRound - 2;
    }
    return $playedTracks,
}
```

Now i'm sitting in a loop (as i mentioned i'm iterating over a player pairs), i have a pair of players and tracks on which they've played on. I also have a set of tracks to assign from, let's say i have tracks with number `1,2,3,4,5` and `$playedTracks` returned `[1,2,3]`. So the choice is either `4 or 5`. I'll pick `4`. As the loop iterates forward more `$playedTracks` are returned and at some point there might be a situation where there's a track to assign, but they've both played on that track for the past two games already.

I'm not sure if my approach was even right and maybe I should consider approaching it player-by-player and not with pairs. Has anybody faced similar problem or could give any helpful words on the matter?

For curious, this is the loop part (yes mysql extension is deprecated, i know):

```
while ($player = mysql_fetch_assoc($allTourneyPlayers)){
    $resultId = $player['resultid'];
    if (in_array($resultId,$checkedResults)){
        //Player already has it's track numbers from opponent
        continue;
    }
    $getCurrentRound = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM roundresults WHERE resultid='$resultId' AND roundNr = '$currentRound'",$connection);
    $opponentTpId = $getCurrentRound['opponentid'];
    $getOpponentDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tourneyplayers WHERE tpid = '$opponentTpId' AND tourneyid='$tourneyid'",$connection);
    $opponentResultId = $getOpponentDetails['resultid'];
    $playedTracks = getPlayedTracks($resultId,$opponentResultId,$currentRound);
    //Add opponent and current player to checked results!
    $checkedResults[] = $opponentResultId;
    $checkedResults[] = $resultId;
}
```

Comment: *"yes mysql extension is deprecated, i know"* then use something else.

Comment: I was expecting some smartass to point out totally irrelevant part to the problem I'm having and was trying to avoid that, glad that you found a workaround to make an even more useless comment than I was expecting.

Comment: you're welcome, give me your website url, I bet I'll make you learn security the hard way. Also your question is confusing, you're making it too complicated. You just want to get a track not payed in the past 2 games for both players, right ? And you have a (black)list of played tracks ?

Comment: I wanted to give background information and what you're seeing here is done fully in a demo environment. The publically accessible site is fully communicating in mysqli, i'm aware of security risks on using mysql, i just feel more at home using that.

Comment: And to answer your question - yes, for both players. I have a list for left available tracks.

Comment: I don't get what you tried but here's how I'd do it: make an array of blacklisted tracks (`$blacklisted_ids = array_merge(array_column($p1, 'id'), array_column($p2, 'id'));`), get all the tracks except them (with a `'SELECT ... WHERE id NOT IN(' . implode(', ', $blacklisted_ids) . ')'`) and pick a random item.

Comment: By blacklisted tracks you mean tracks on which these players have played on ?

Comment: Yes, the tracks that shouldn't be played for the actual round

Comment: I'll mingle with your suggestion and see what comes out of it, thanks for the advice

Comment: How do you suggest to overcome a situation where final pairs will not have any available tracks left to play (as first pairs might randomly get assigned values which might suit for final pairs)

Comment: Get more tracks in your list ?

Comment: The amount of tracks is limited and final, but track list is never smaller than an amount of pairs. At worst case, it's the same as the number of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gonna post the answer if someone else runs into trouble next time.

List of tracks `$listOfTracks = [1,2,3,4,5]`. These are all the tracks.

Available tracks per pair can be added into an array (where indexes refer to pairs):

```
$availableTracks = [[1,4],[3,5],[2,3,5],[1,2],[2,4]]
```

This array could be visualized as a tree. The first combination which has all the track numbers is a suitable one (in example above it could be `1,3,5,2,4` or `4,3,5,1,2` depending on which algorithm is chosen to iterate through the tree. Obviously there could be more than one/two solutions for each, but the task is not to find them all just the first one).

One of the algorithms to iterate through the tree would be "choose left" where always the most left node is selected if it's possible (based on previous example `$availableTracks = [[1,4],[3,5],[2,3,5],[1,2],[2,4]]`:

```
Current node [1,4], Select 1, move downwards - $selectedNumbers = [1]
Current node [3,5], Select 3, move downwards - $selectedNumbers = [1,3]
Current node [2,3,5], Select 2, move downwards - $selectedNumbers = [1,3,2]
Current node [1,2], 1 and 2 are only available nodes, both are used, move upwards and continue with different node.
Current node [2,3,5], 2 wasnt suitable, 3 is not suitable (as already used), Select 5, move downwards - $selectedNumbers = [1,3,5].  
Current node [1,2], 1 is not suitable (as already used), Select 2, move downwards - `$selectedNumbers = [1,3,5,2]`
Current node [2,4], 2 is not suitable (as already used), Select 4, array has reached the same length as number of pairs, found suitable.
Final list: `$selectedNumbers = [1,3,5,2,4]`
```